# What can I do to debug and avoid decoding artifacts with RTP in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-streaming, vp9

I do encoding and decoding of a VP9 RTP stream programmatically, and I am experiencing occasional colorful artifacts like these:

[image]

In the ffmpeg log (both when using `ffplay` and my own code), this usually coincides with such messages

```
[sdp @ 0x14de06880] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[sdp @ 0x14de06880] RTP: missed 18 packets
```

So presumably, the demuxer can't wait any longer for packets and the decoder produces something incomplete. Is there a way to either detect this and drop incomplete frames or what should I be looking at to fix this?

The VP9 support in ffmpeg's RTP is apparently experimental, so maybe that is also a problem, but I am hoping there's maybe some decoder parameters that makes it degrade more gracefully.

Comment: The problem with modern video codecs is that most frames depend on other frames. It’s how compression is so good. What you see most likely is the result of a dropped frame. [Edited repost from earlier.]

Comment: Obviously, but it seems to me that realtime streaming should deal with packet loss more gracefully. Missing a frame is not such a problem, but displaying strong artifacts like this may be. And I'm wondering if the issue is more on the RTP side or the decoder.

Comment: If your aim is to avoid dropped packets, write your own protocol. If your aim is to deal with dropped packets "more gracefully", write your own codec.

Comment: So you would say that this is normal for a codec/for vp9 that missing data shows up like this? I don't know how vp9 works, so I couldn't say. I'm more wondering if this is in fact a decoding artifact or if I should look somewhere else for the issue.

Comment: I actually switched to Vp8 as a test, and it does look much better. The bitrate is way higher, but it seems to deal better with lost rtp packets. So I would surmise this is either ffmpeg's use of libvpx or in libvpx itself.